# Embedding PDF in VF site

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, pdf

I want to embed a pdf in a VF site.

I'm using the "object, embed" method and that works fine for a VF page, however when attempting to make that page externally available via a site, the pdf is no longer available.

Is this a limitation, or do I have the profile permissions incorrect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can embed a PDF in a VF page via a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). For example...

```
 <apex:page controller="myPDF" sidebar="false" contentType="application/pdf">
    <script>
      window.location.href = "data:application/pdf;base64,{!myData}";
    </script>
 </apex:page>
```

You will need to test on different browsers. Note that you need the base64 encoded data.